# Why button tags disable my actionlink?

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc-4

I try to use css for my actionlinks, in the aim to they look like a simple button.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Ajouter une thématique", "AddThematic", new { ParentId = "var1", ParentName = "var2", IsAdult = "var3" }, new { @id = "AddThematic", @style="color:black" })
```

it works perfectly if i don't add css with the button tags.

```
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
      @Html.ActionLink("Ajouter une thématique", "AddThematic", new { ParentId = "var1", ParentName = "var2", IsAdult = "var3" }, new { @id = "AddThematic", @style="color:black" })
   </button>
```

In this case you can click on the button, but the page doesn't reload and you don't go to the page "Delete"

In don't understand why it doesn't work.

I also use JQuery to change data into the ActionLink :

```
        $('#AddThematic').click(function () {
            var ParentId = $('#ParentThematic').val();
            var ParentName = $('#ParentThematic option:selected').text();
            var IsAdult = $('#ChkIsAdult').is(':checked').toString();
            this.href = this.href.replace("var1", ParentId);
            this.href = this.href.replace("var2", ParentName);
            this.href = this.href.replace("var3", IsAdult);
        });
```

Have you an idea ?

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
@Html.ActionLink("Ajouter une thématique", "AddThematic", new { ParentId = "var1", ParentName = "var2", IsAdult = "var3" }, new { @id = "AddThematic", @Class="btn btn-default btn-xs" })
```

this works good but how to put the glyphicon into the button ?

finnaly i use this :

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Ajouter une thématique", "AddThematic", new { ParentId = "var1", ParentName = "var2", IsAdult = "var3" }, new { @id = "AddThematic", @Class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus btn btn-default btn-xs" })
```

[How to apply two CSS classes to a single div/span](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482677/how-to-apply-two-css-classes-to-a-single-div-span)

this link and your answers help me a lot thanks !

Comment: Change it to an anchor tag like my example below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

glyphicon glyphicon-plus@Html.ActionLink creates the button markup for you, so what you are doing there is wrapping a link in a button.  If you want the actionlink to look like a button just add a style to it.

For an icon do this:

```
<a class="btn" href="@Url.Action("AddThematic", new {id = Model.CodeTemplateId})" id="A3" title="Help"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></a>
```

Comment: I do that because i want the glyphicon into the button

Comment: It works but the glyphicon is on the right of the button and not inside

Answer (score 2):

Please use the below code instead of using button.

If you need to set the Icon then you have to use the 
**View** code as like below

```
  <button id="btn" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" location="@Url.Action("AddThematic", new { ParentId = "var1", ParentName = "var2", IsAdult = "var3" })">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
  Ajouter une thématique
  </button>
```

**javascript**

```
 $('#btn').click(function () {
          var loc = $(this).attr('location');
    if (loc != null) {
        window.location = loc;
    }
    });
```

If you don't need icon means just use the below code

I have added the class as "btn btn-default btn-xs" in the htmlattribute.
Please try this one.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Ajouter une thématique", "AddThematic", new { ParentId = "var1", ParentName = "var2", IsAdult = "var3" }, new { @id = "AddThematic", @style="color:black", @class="btn btn-default btn-xs" })
```

This will helps you to show the action link as button in your view

Comment: It works but how to put the glyphicon into the button ?

Comment: Have you need it inside of the button or in the front of the button

Comment: It's inside the button

Comment: in above code i have added id and loaction attributes to the button and used them through the javascript

Answer (score 0):

HTML forbids buttons from containing interactive content (i.e. other buttons and links).

The button is being disabled by the browser in an attempt to recover from your error.

Write valid HTML and [test it with a validator](http://validator.w3.org).