# Can we have two class attributes for a single div element separately?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am working on a React application. I want to have a div with a conditional class as shown below:

```
<div class="defaultClass1 defaultClass2" class = {player_color === 1? "bg-green" :"bg-opponent"}>
      <p>Body</p>
</div>
```

I find that, the class that is written second completely overrides the prev. So is there an easy way i can get the effect of both classes without repeating the default class inside the "bg-green" and "bg-opponent" ?

Comment: maybe you will fund soliton here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482677/how-to-apply-two-css-classes-to-a-single-element/38942058

Comment: @AbdullahAlNoor .. I did check that question.. that is completely different, it doesn't deal with conditional classes...anyway, the solution by did help me! thank you btw

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like below should work. Check and try

```html
<div className={"defaultClass1 defaultClass2 " + (player_color === 1? 'bg-green' :'bg-opponent')}>
<p>Body</p>
```

Comment: Thanks... that indeed solve the issue.. I didnt find this solution in first place when i was browsing... Later i found this : https://scriptverse.academy/tutorials/reactjs-add-class-conditionally.html   which might be useful for others!

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot ,
You can have the classes separate in css and still call both just using the class="class1 class2" in the html. You just need a space between one or more class names

Comment: Yeah.. i know classes can be added using spaces.. but my larger question is how to achieve what i need.. i.e how to use conditional classes (if else)

Answer (score 0):

```
const myClassNames = `defaultClass1 defaultClass2 bg-${player_color === 1 ? 'green' : 'opponent'}
<div class={myClassNames}>
      <p>Body</p>
</div>
```

Or you can use [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames)

Comment: thank you.. the link you provided is indeed useful!