# Can we use two bootstrap class at same time?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

Is there a way to combine `class="text-left"` & `class = 'text-danger'`of bootstrap, because I need to align the text to left and color the text red at the same time

Comment: Try class="text-left text-danger"

Comment: It is possible.

Comment: See also [How to apply two CSS classes to a single element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5482677/215552)